# Find numbers with the sum yielding 2017 and with the maximum product

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization

How do I find the natural numbers $n$ and $a_1, a_2, a_3,..., a_n$ so that $a_1+a_2+...+a_n = 2017$ and the product is the maximum possible? In my opinion, all the numbers except for $a_{2017}$ must be $2$, and $a_{2017}$ must be equal to $1$, then the product will be $2^{2016}$. But how do I prove that it is the maximum product and that we should have $2016$ numbers?

Comment: Actually, note that you can replace three 2s with two 3s to increase the product, since 2^3=8<3^2=9

Answer (score 2):

What you have doesn't add up (if you have $2016$ $2$s and a $1$, their sum is $4033$), so presumably you mean $1008$ $2$s and a $1$ for $2^{1008}$. But this can easily be improved to $3\times 2^{1007}$ by replacing the last $+2+1$ with $+3$. For this reason you can't have any $1$s.

Similarly, you can't have any number greater than $4$. If you have an $n$, where $n\geq 5$, you are better off replacing it with $(n-2)+2$, since $2(n-2)>n$. In fact, you can replace $4$ by $2+2$ without changing the product, so there is always an optimal solution which only uses the numbers $2$ and $3$ (it may not be unique). So you just need to look for numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $2a+3b=2017$ and $2^a3^b$ is as large as possible. Jgon's observation should allow you to complete the answer.

Answer (score 2):

(Apologies, I solved it in the general case) This is quite a good problem:
We are going to use the following:

AM-GM inequality: $$\frac{a_1+a_2 \dots a_n}{n}\geq (\prod_1^na_i)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ for $a_i \geq 0$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ with equality if and only if $a_1=a_2=\dots = a_n$

Hence you have $\frac{2017}{n}\geq (\prod_1^na_i)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ which implies 
$\prod_1^na_i \leq (\frac{2017}{n})^n$

Now you want to maximise $(\frac{2017}{n})^n$ with respect to $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
Differentiate with respect to $n$ to get $2017^n(\frac{1}{n})^n(\log(\frac{2017}{n})-1)$

You can now check that $x=\frac{2017}{e}$ is a local maximum. 
Also note, that this maximum is achieved when taking $a_i=\frac{2017}{\frac{2017}{e}}=e$

The only problem is that this $n$ is not a positive integer but you can avoid that by looking at the $2$ closest positive integers to $\frac{2017}{e}$ and see the value your product attains for each of them

Comment: The problem is asking for the $a_i$s to be integers, not just $n$.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it after I had posted the solution and hence the apology on the first line

Comment: Incidentally your answer is not always correct even for the problem you considered. If we are trying to get a sum of $53$ rather than $2017$, $n=20$ makes $\frac{53}n$ as close to $e$ as possible, but $\big(\frac{53}{19}\big)^{19}>\big(\frac{53}{20}\big)^{20}$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the rate of increasing before the critical point is not equal to the rate of decrease after it. Will edit the answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you use $k$ a total of $n_k$ times.

Your product will be $1^{n_1}\times 2^{n_2} \times 3^{n_3}\times\dots$.

Instead of maximising this, try to maximise its logarithm $L$:

$L = n_1\log1+n_2\log2+n_3\log 3+\dots$.

You have the constraint $n_1+2n_2+3n_3+\dots = 2017$.

If I increase $n_i$ and decrease $n_j$, to keep the constraint happy, I have to have $i\delta n_i + j\delta n_j = 0$. The change will increase $L$ if $\log i \delta n_i + \log j \delta n_j > 0$, that is, $\frac{1}{i}\log i > \frac{1}{j}\log j$.

Therefore, I should find out which $i$ has the maximum possible $\frac{\log i}{i}$, and make that $n_i$ as large as possible.

No matter what base you choose for the logarithm, $\frac{\log{x}}{x}$ is maximised when $x=e$. For whole numbers, the maximum is when $x=3$. If 2017 was a multiple of 3, you couldn't improve on just using threes. As it is, you should either use 672 threes, or 671 threes and some fours or twos.